# Get current language of the Ionic App

Tags: wordpress, ionic-framework, woocommerce, ionic3

I am developing an Ionic 3 App based on WooCommerce database using rest API.

I use Polylang Plugin to translate my WorrdPress website, and because this plugin does not support rest API, I decided to use "include" parameter
when I query categories, in order to get them in one language.

Ex:

```
this.http.get(this.config.setUrl('GET', '/wp-json/wc/v2/products/categories?', {
  per_page: 120, include: '151,152,929'
})
```

Is there a way to check the current language of the app, and based on that to query certain categories?

Something like:

```
if ( currentLang = 'en' ){
this.http.get(this.config.setUrl('GET', '/wp-json/wc/v2/products/categories?', {
per_page: 120, include: '151,152,929'
}else ...
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `ngx-translate`

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
  console.log(this.translate.getBrowserLang());
}
```

Hint:
Ionic native Globalization plugin is deprecated
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization#deprecation-notice

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Ionic native Globalization](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/globalization/) plugin for get current language,

```
import { Globalization } from '@ionic-native/globalization';

this.globalization.getPreferredLanguage()
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you!

I have used `getDefaultLang()` and it worked smooth.

Looks like this:
                `this.http.get(this.config.setUrl('GET', '/wp-json/wc/v2/products/categories?', {
                    per_page: 120, include: '151,152,929'
                })else ...`

Then on my language switcher I am setting the default language and calling the `load()` function in order to query the categories for the new default language.
This way my app does not refresh when I change the language and provides good experience.

Thank you for helping!